# "Insufficient system resources" when trying to run "git init"

Tags: windows, github

I am trying to create a Jenkins job and noticed that whenever I try to build my maven project, it exits showing the following error in the log (Which happens after about 2 minutes and after the memory usage reaches almost 99%):

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init C:\Users\rami_\.jenkins\workspace\Soc
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:994)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:749)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1222)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1300)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:505)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1211)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:636)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:508)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1906)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git init C:\Users\rami_\.jenkins\workspace\Soc" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error launching git: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.


    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2608)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2538)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2534)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1920)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:992)
... 12 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

So I tried to run git init using CMD to check if the problem is Jenkins related or not, and I got exactly the same behavior, which is the two minutes wait, and when memory usage reaches 95-100% it exits and shows the following message:

```
error launching git: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
```

I have 12 GB installed on my PC and the project I am working with is rather small. Memory usage before running the command is usually around 50%.
I saw some people suggesting to perform "scan disk for errors" which I tried and did not work.
Worth noting that Github desktop is working flawlessly.

Comment: Does large file exist in your repo?

Comment: For even more verbose output use following: GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 hit

Comment: GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git clone <your repo url>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. No large files exist in the repo. I will post the verbose output tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by uninstalling Git, removing all its files under AppData, restarting, and then installing it again.